# Error running deep learning image classification example with Mxnet library on Python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, image-recognition, mxnet, imagenet

I am trying to run the [this image classification example](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/notebooks/predict-with-pretrained-model.ipynb) that uses [Mxnet library](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet) in python and the pre-trained deep learning model Inception-BN. The execution throws and error on this line: `prob = model.predict(batch)[0]` with the error message:

```
MXNetError: InferShape Error in ch_concat_3c_chconcat: [14:35:56] src/operator/./concat-inl.h:152: Check failed: (dshape[j]) == (tmp[j]) Incorrect shape[2]: (1,320,15,15). (first input shape: (1,576,14,14))
```

I tried downloading the Inception-BN model again to make sure it was up to date but it didn't make a difference. I do suspect the problem could be on line: `model = mx.model.FeedForward.load(prefix, num_round, ctx=mx.gpu(), numpy_batch_size=1)` where I had to change **gpu** for **cpu** since my server is not equiped with a gpu. Nevertheless the error doesn't seem to point on that direction.

Any idea how to fix it? Is using a cpu instead of a gpu a problem other than a lower performance?

Finally here is the complete error information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MXNetError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-98e51e4226e1> in <module>()
      1 # Get prediction probability of 1000 classes from model
----> 2 prob = model.predict(batch)[0]
      3 # Argsort, get prediction index from largest prob to lowest
      4 pred = np.argsort(prob)[::-1]
      5 # Get top1 label

/users/CREATE/olb/mxnet/python/mxnet/model.pyc in predict(self, X, num_batch, return_data, reset)
    589         data_shapes = X.provide_data
    590         data_names = [x[0] for x in data_shapes]
--> 591         self._init_predictor(data_shapes)
    592         batch_size = X.batch_size
    593         data_arrays = [self._pred_exec.arg_dict[name] for name in data_names]

/users/CREATE/olb/mxnet/python/mxnet/model.pyc in _init_predictor(self, input_shapes)
    520         # for now only use the first device
    521         pred_exec = self.symbol.simple_bind(
--> 522             self.ctx[0], grad_req='null', **dict(input_shapes))
    523         pred_exec.copy_params_from(self.arg_params, self.aux_params)
    524 

/users/CREATE/olb/mxnet/python/mxnet/symbol.pyc in simple_bind(self, ctx, grad_req, type_dict, **kwargs)
    623         if type_dict is None:
    624             type_dict = {k: mx_real_t for k in self.list_arguments()}
--> 625         arg_shapes, _, aux_shapes = self.infer_shape(**kwargs)
    626         arg_types, _, aux_types = self.infer_type(**type_dict)
    627         if arg_shapes == None or arg_types == None:

/users/CREATE/olb/mxnet/python/mxnet/symbol.pyc in infer_shape(self, *args, **kwargs)
    410             The order is in the same order as list_auxiliary()
    411         """
--> 412         return self._infer_shape_impl(False, *args, **kwargs)
    413 
    414     def infer_shape_partial(self, *args, **kwargs):

/users/CREATE/olb/mxnet/python/mxnet/symbol.pyc in _infer_shape_impl(self, partial, *args, **kwargs)
    470             ctypes.byref(aux_shape_ndim),
    471             ctypes.byref(aux_shape_data),
--> 472             ctypes.byref(complete)))
    473         if complete.value != 0:
    474             arg_shapes = [

/users/CREATE/olb/mxnet/python/mxnet/base.pyc in check_call(ret)
     75     """
     76     if ret != 0:
---> 77         raise MXNetError(py_str(_LIB.MXGetLastError()))
     78 
     79 def c_str(string):

MXNetError: InferShape Error in ch_concat_3c_chconcat: [14:35:56] src/operator/./concat-inl.h:152: Check failed: (dshape[j]) == (tmp[j]) Incorrect shape[2]: (1,320,15,15). (first input shape: (1,576,14,14))
```

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned notebook is moved to [notebooks repository](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-notebooks/blob/master/python/moved-from-mxnet/predict-with-pretrained-model.ipynb). I tried to run it today and was able to run the tutorial successfully. 
The issue was in old model because the change in interface broke backward compatibility. Seems like they have uploaded the new trained inception-BN model.

Posting this if someone else also got this error, just download the new model [here](http://data.mxnet.io/mxnet/models/imagenet/inception-bn/).